# Como hacer un CASE WHEN de un Campo Nvarchar que a veces es Nulo o vacio?

Tags: sql, stored-procedure, sap

Bueno tengo la siguiente Consulta, es un procedimiento almacenado para HANA STUDIO tengo el Campo **A."NumAtCard"** el cual es de tipo nvarchar lo que sucede es que muchas veces el campo estara vacío o sera nulo y quisiera saber como realizar un CASE para que la consulta no me tire ese valor vació o Nulo

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SBO_COMP_RETENCION(
    IN FECHAINI DATE,
    IN FECHAFIN DATE,
    IN FECHAUS DATE
)
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT
A."CardCode" "Cod Cliente", 
A."CardName" "Cliente",
C."City",
A."Address",
A."U_nrc_prov",
C."U_NIT" "NIT",       
A."NumAtCard" "Documento",
(select SUM(x."LineTotal") FROM "PCH1" x WHERE x."DocEntry" = A."DocEntry") AS "Importe",
"SBO_CANTIDADCONLETRA"(IFNULL ((SELECT ROUND(X."WTAmnt",2) FROM  "PCH5" X WHERE X."AbsEntry" =  A."DocEntry" AND X."WTCode" = '1%RF'), 0))|| ' DOLARES' AS "CantidadEnLetras",
IFNULL ((SELECT X."WTAmnt" FROM  "PCH5" X WHERE X."AbsEntry" =  A."DocEntry" AND X."WTCode" = '1%RF'), 0) as "Retención",
A."DocDate" "Fecha",
'Factura Proveedores' as "Tipo",
'RET 1%RF' AS "COD"
FROM "OPCH" A
left JOIN "OCRD" C ON A."CardCode" = C."CardCode"
WHERE A."CANCELED" NOT IN('C','Y')
AND A."DocDate" BETWEEN FECHAINI AND FECHAFIN;
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es muy sencillo, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
...
,CASE
    when A."NumAtCard" is null then 'No tiene'
    when A."NumAtCard"='' then 'No capturada'
    else A."NumAtCard"
end "Documento",
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Si está usando SQL Server, puede usar [ISNULL()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_isnull.asp).

La función `ISNULL` recibe dos parámetros:

1. Valor a verificar si es `NULL`.
2. En caso de ser `NULL`, usar este valor.

Ya que no especificas cuál es el valor que retorna NULL, este es un ejemplo para validar que "si el campo `C."City"` es NULL", retornar otro valor.

*Ejemplo: Si la ciudad es `NULL`, mostrar el texto "Sin Ciudad"*.

```
SELECT ISNULL(C.[City], 'Sin Ciudad')
FROM <tu_tabla>
```